# Handling invalid (wild) GPS fixes sometimes returned by a device

Tags: android

I've got a GPS tracking application that occasionally (say once a month) returns a bunch of wild/invalid fixes.  Is there a strategy for handling this situation?

Comment: If the application is tracking you let say once at every 10 minutes then make a difference between the coordonates you can't change position in 10 minutes more then 10 km ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `getAccuracy()` to check and see how precise is your GPS fix and throw away anything which does not fit. 100m is a good threshold for outdoor applications.